# JBoss Too Many Files Open Error

Tags: jboss

Just in the last week I have been having issues with accessing a JBoss (v 4.2.2) web application.  When I go to the home page, I get a java.lang.NullPointerException error page.  After looking at the JBoss log output, it appears that too many files are open, so how would I go about closing these files?  Here is the output from the JBoss log:

> ```
>   ERROR [[jsp]] Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
>     java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/local/jboss-4.2.2.GA/server/default/work/jboss.web/localhost/catissuecore/org/apache/jsp/pages/content/home/Error_jsp.java (Too many open files)
>     at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
>     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:179)
>     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:70)
>     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:152)
>     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:306)
>     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:286)
>     at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:273)
>     at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:566)
>     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:316)
>     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:336)
>     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:654)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:447)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:379)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:292)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:423)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:270)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
>     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
>     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262)
>     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
>     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
>     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:446)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
> ```

```
    ERROR [[localhost]] Exception Processing ErrorPage[exceptionType=java.lang.Exception, location=/pages/content/home/Error.jsp]
    org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:574)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:316)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:336)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:265)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:654)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:447)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:379)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:423)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:270)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:446)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
    Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/local/jboss-4.2.2.GA/server/default/work/jboss.web/localhost/catissuecore/org/apache/jsp/pages/content/home/Error_jsp.java (Too many open files)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:179)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:70)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:152)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:306)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:286)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:273)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:566)
    ... 21 more
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all you want to determine what file(s) remain open.  I'm assuming your server runs linux, so once you know JBoss'es PID

```
ps ax | grep something-that-makes-your-jboss-process-unique
```

you can do

```
ls -l /proc/jbossPID/fd
```

to get a nice list of files that are open at that instant.

Then **jbossPID** is the number you found with **`ps`** .

What you're going to do next depends a bit on what you see here:

1. you may just need to up the number of files the server can open a bit with ulimit (also look at systemwide limits on your server)
2. maybe you spot a number of files your application forgot to close
3. ....

But to close these files / get rid of the open files you'll have to restart the JBoss instance.

Answer (score 7):

Assuming you are running on linux (or other *NIX) then there is a file descriptor limit of 1024 per process. In Unix everything is a file - including a socket, device and so on. A wat to have a look at this is to run the lsof command (only as root) - it will show you all the open file descriptors.

In order to fix that, edit the file in /etc/security/limits.conf and add the following lines and restart your jboss.

```
jboss          soft    nofile          16384
jboss          hard    nofile          16384
```

(assuming your jboss is run by the "jboss" user)

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem also (on linux).
What I did:

1. Check limits : ulimit -a
2. check 2 lines in output:

```
    open files                      (-n) 1024
    max user processes              (-u) 1024
```

1. Set both parameters ( for example in your .bash_profile )

```
    ulimit -n 100000
    ulimit -u 100000
```

In my case I had to change both parameters to solve the problem.