# Wildfly - Too many open files

Tags: java, wildfly

Im using wildfly (wildfly-10.0.0.Final) as application server, when i deployed abt 30 wars file. each war send rest api to communicate with others. sometime i got the error as below:

> [org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient] (EJB default - 2) I/O
>   exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to
>   {}->http://localhost:8080: Too many open files
>   [org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient] (EJB default - 2)
>   Retrying connect to {}->http://localhost:8080
>   [org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient] (EJB default - 2) I/O
>   exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to
>   {}->http://localhost:8080: Too many open files
>   [org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient] (EJB default - 2)
>   Retrying connect to {}->http://localhost:8080
>   [org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient] (EJB default - 2) I/O
>   exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to
>   {}->http://localhost:8080: Too many open files
>   [org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient] (EJB default - 2)
>   Retrying connect to {}->http://localhost:8080 Exception occurred while
>   getting the tenant specific token : java.lang.Exception:
>   RESTEASY004655: Unable to invoke request

I already increase 'open files' configuration like this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572494/jboss-too-many-files-open-error)

But can not resolve the issue. i really grateful if any suggestion for that?

Java, wildfly

Answer (score 1):

You did increase the limit of open files. However, did you restart wildfly after that? And can you post more logs of what is going on? Also, according to the link [JBoss Too Many Files Open Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572494/jboss-too-many-files-open-error)posted by you in the question itself, can you please do the following if you're running a linux like operating system:

Once you know JBoss'es PID

ps ax | grep something-that-makes-your-jboss-process-unique
you can do

ls -l /proc/jbosspid/fd

If you're running Windows, try running the tasklist command instead of ps as following tasklist | FIND "file.extension"

Also, after that, you can do DIR instead of ls, like dir "\search term*" /s