# How can I solve the "Too many open files" error in Wildfly?

Tags: file, wildfly

First of all, I'm sorry for asking this, as I know it has been asked several times in the past (i.e, [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56624315/wildfly-too-many-open-files)
[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572494/jboss-too-many-files-open-error))... but I cannot fix it in our server, no matter what I do. I've done everything that has been said here before or that I've found elsewhere, but nothing seems to work.

The problem is, as many others have said before, that everytime I upload a file to the server, other file (file descriptor, I think) remains open although it has been deleted. Something like this:

```
lr-x------. 1 wildfly wildfly 64 Mar  30 10:16 940 -\> /var/wildfly/wildfly-19.1.0.Final/standalone/tmp/gsRest.war/undertow4244631137444366573upload (deleted)
lr-x------. 1 wildfly wildfly 64 Mar  30 10:16 941 -\> /var/wildfly/wildfly-19.1.0.Final/standalone/tmp/gsRest.war/undertow4327579555486420276upload (deleted)
lr-x------. 1 wildfly wildfly 64 Mar  30 10:16 942 -\> /var/wildfly/wildfly-19.1.0.Final/standalone/tmp/gsRest.war/undertow3238368538171822505upload (deleted)
lr-x------. 1 wildfly wildfly 64 Mar  30 10:16 943 -\> /var/wildfly/wildfly-19.1.0.Final/standalone/tmp/gsRest.war/undertow6318039346308593432upload (deleted)
```

We are using Wildfly 19.1.0.Final, with Undertow 2.1.0. I know there was a bug in previous versions, but it should be fixed in this version... I really just don't know where else to look or what else to do to solve this.

To upload the file to the server, our code is very simple:

First, we retrive the inputStream from the HttpServletRequest (the "fichero" object is a custom one):

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    ...
    Part filePart = request.getPart("dataFichero");
    InputStream fileContent = filePart.getInputStream();
    fichero.setData(ByteStreams.toByteArray(fileContent));

    fileService.uploadFile(fichero, deviceId);
    ...
}
```

Then, in that method, we do the following:

```
try (FileOutputStream fileOuputStream = new FileOutputStream(path + File.separator + file.getId().toString())) {
    fileOuputStream.write(fichero.getData());
}
```

We've tried with the following modification:

```
File file = new File(path + File.separator + fichero.getId().toString());
FileOutputStream fileOuputStream = new FileOutputStream(file); 
try {
    fileOuputStream.write(fichero.getData());
} catch (Exception e) {
    logger.error(e);
} finally {
    fileOuputStream.flush();
    fileOuputStream.close();
    file.delete();
}
```

Then I found something that supposedly resolve the issue, but it didn't work either:

```
File file = null;

try {
    String key = System.currentTimeMillis() + "-" + UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    file = File.createTempFile(key, ".tmp");
                 
    try (FileOutputStream fileOuputStream = new FileOutputStream(ruta + File.separator + fichero.getId().toString())) {

        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        int read;

        while ((read = inputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            fileOuputStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }

        fileOuputStream.flush();                   
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e);
    }
} finally {
    if (file != null) {
        file.delete();
    }
}
```

As I said, it didn't work. Instead, it created TWO "undertowXXXXXupload (deleted)" files for every file uploaded.

Before closing this question saying that it's duplicated... has anyone any idea of why this is happening? What can I do to avoid the undertowXXXupload files? It's a very annoying issue (our server crashes from time to time due to this) and I'm very frustated not being able to solve it. I really hope anyone can point me in the right direction :(

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry Jose nvm I'm not familiar with Java tbh

Comment: Have you tried closing the `InputStream` as well?

Comment: I haven't tried that! I'm making tests with and without closing the inputStream, and... I have to say I'm confused by the output. At first it seemed to be the cause, but now those files are not showing up again without closing it. I will keep trying tomorrow.

Thanks for the tip! I never thought about the inputStream as the possible cause of this.

Comment: Closing the InputStream finally solved the issue!!! I was always focused on the OutputStream and never thought about that. Also, I had to remove the "file.delete()" line, which was also causing problems. You saved my day. Thanks, @JamesR.Perkins!!!